# Warning/Notice/Strict with Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon 1.3.3 and PHP 5.4.
In my controller i have something like:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
    $data = json_encode(['some data']);

    $this->response->setContent($data);
    return $this->response->send();
}
```

If I put an "echo" in this action, I can't see it anywhere and i think this is realted to the fact that Phalcon use buffer output ([It is possible to get Phalcon\Mvc\View rendered output in variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901805/it-is-possible-to-get-phalcon-mvc-view-rendered-output-in-variable))

But that's not really my problem, my problem is that if I have warnings/notice about missing variable, or undeclared constant or using deprecated methods, I can't see those on the rendered page.
I can see them in the logs but not the page itself which is a bit annoying when developing. In production obviously it's not a problem.

PS: I have "display_errors" and "display_startup_errors" set to 1 and if I put an exist before rendering the page I see all the warnings

Comment: My guess, you set the content of the response after you echo? I think that phalcon would check if `$response->content` is set and only if it isn't puts in `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: But is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, assuming you use the echo for debugging purposes only: use `die()`.

Comment: Well i don't want to use echo for debugging, I see want to be able to see normal PHP warnings. Looking at the error log is "slower".

Comment: In that case you're looking in the wrong place. Take a look at [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/index.php). Depending on your OS you can install it using `apt-get install php5-xdebug`. Also read phalcons own guide on [Debugging Applications](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/debug.html)

Comment: Also put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the start of your code.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) is already there. XDebug might work but I just need to see warnings/notices

Answer (score 1):

I use this to return json:

```
    $expireDate = new \DateTime();

    $this->response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');
    $this->response->setExpires($expireDate);
    $this->response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $this->response->sendHeaders();
    echo json_encode(array('response' => $response, 'error' => $this->api_error));
```

and in index.php

```
/**
 * Handle the request
 */
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
//disable view service in general
$application->useImplicitView(false);
```

if you want to disable view rendering just for some places, you can use in controller:

```
$this->view->disable(); 
echo $data;
```

Comment: That kinda work because I'm building an API and I don't need views. However I see this being a problem for someone using views...

Comment: This code is from my API and i don't use views service, so it's disabled in index.php with this line: $application->useImplicitView(false); and if there are actions where you have to use views and some, where don't, so $this->view->disable(); (called from any controller) is very handy :)